# How do I print the value at given index in two dimensional array of pointers?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to print all the values in a two dimensional array. I come from Java and I'm having issues figuring this out in C. How do you access the value at two given indices in C?

```
void PrintArrayByPointer(int *ptrToArray)
{
    int i,j;

    printf("\nPrint Array By Pointers: \n");
    for(i=0; i<ROWS; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<COLS; j++)
        {
            // print the value here
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I believe it should be `i*COLS+j`

Comment: It depends on how you store the two dimensional data in a one dimensional array such as `ptrToArray`.

Comment: Assuming array data type `double` and `ROWS` & `COLS` are declared global ......... `printf("%f",&ptrToArray[i*ROWS + j])` inside `j-loop`.

Comment: @Dukeling: that would be true if ptrToArray were an array of pointers to arrays, but the OP said it's a single 2D array, so because it degrades to a pointer upon passing to a function, you cannot expect `ptrToArray[i][j]` to work, because there is no way to know the length of each row.

Comment: Can you show where you set up the data you pass to this function? As shown, `ptrToArray` points to a 1-D array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%d ", ptrToArray[i*COLS + j]);
```

I assume here that your array is stored in row-major order, which is pretty typical in C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is a better way to change declaration to next one:

```
void PrintArrayByPointer(int **ptrToArray)
```

and you can access to array like this:

```
printf("Value[%d][%d]=%d", i, j, ptrToArray[i][j]);
```

In your case you should calculate position of your element in array like this:

```
printf("Value[%d][%d]=%d", i, j, ptrToArray[i*COLS+j]);
```